# Getting the maximum number of nodes in a tree

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, tree, time-complexity

I would like to get the max number of nodes in a tree. So the max number of nodes is 5 in the example below because there are 5 nodes in the first tree.

Example input is as follows;
`[['1 3'], ['1 4'], ['3 5'], ['4 6'], ['7 8']]` and the tree becomes like this;

[image]

I have written this code and it is working but is it possible to write more efficient code? Because the time complexity is more than O(N²) right now.

```
function getMaxNumberOfNodes(edges) {
    let nodes = new Map();
    for (let i = 0; i < edges.length; i++) {
        let firstValue = parseInt(edges[i][0].charAt(0));
        let secondValue = parseInt(edges[i][0].charAt(2));

        if (nodes.has(firstValue)) {
            let tempArray = nodes.get(firstValue)
            tempArray.push(secondValue)
            nodes.set(firstValue, tempArray);
        }
        else {
            nodes.set(firstValue, [secondValue]);
        }
    }
    console.log(nodes) // Map(4) { 1 => [ 3, 4 ], 3 => [ 5 ], 4 => [ 6 ], 7 => [ 8 ] }
    let connectedNodes = new Map();
    for (let node of nodes.keys()) {
        let nodeValue = nodes.get(node);
        let tempArray = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < nodeValue.length; i++) {
            if (nodes.has(nodeValue[i])) {
                tempArray = tempArray.concat(nodes.get(nodeValue[i]));
            }
        }
        connectedNodes.set(node, nodes.get(node).concat(tempArray));
    }
    console.log(connectedNodes) // Map(4) { 1 => [ 3, 4, 5, 6 ], 3 => [ 5 ], 4 => [ 6 ], 7 => [ 8 ] }

    let maxNumberOfNodes = 0;

    for (let node of connectedNodes.keys()) {
        maxNumberOfNodes = Math.max(connectedNodes.get(node).length, maxNumberOfNodes);
    }
    return maxNumberOfNodes + 1;
}

console.log(getMaxNumberOfNodes([['1 3'], ['1 4'], ['3 5'], ['4 6'], ['7 8']])) // 5
```

Comment: Not sure if this might be better placed on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are the branches in the input guaranteed to come top-down? Eg would `[['2 3'], ['1, 2']]` be a possible input, or not? (If impossible, that'll make the code a lot easier to manage)

Comment: Yes they are from top to down. [['2 3'], ['1 2']] is possible input because tree will be 1 -> 2-> 3

Comment: I would imagine `[['1 2'], ['2 1']]` wouldn't be a valid input right? as that would create a cycle... Or would there be two different 1s?

Comment: Yes, [['1 2'], ['2 1']] is not a valid input

Comment: This is basically counting the number of connected components, just keeping a track of the number of nodes visited

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Can you show how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```js
let inputTest = [
  ['1 3'],
  ['1 4'],
  ['3 5'],
  ['4 6'],
  ['7 8']
];

function groupByRootNode(inp) {
  let root = new Map();
  let nodes = new Map();

  inp.forEach(pair => {
    let [prev, next] = pair[0].split(' ');
    //find the group either on the nodes map or the root map
    let group = nodes.get(prev) || root.get(prev);
    //check if the root node exists already
    let oldRoot = root.get(next);
    //if group doesn't exist
    if (!group) {
      //else group doesn't exist
      //we create a new tree group
      //prev is a new root node
      group = oldRoot || [];
      root.set(prev, group);
    }
    //add pair to existing group
    group.push(pair);
    //record new node as part of group
    nodes.set(next, group);

    if (oldRoot) {
      //if theres a root node with next, then that is no longer a root node
      root.delete(next);
    }
  });
  return root;
}

console.log(Array.from(groupByRootNode(inputTest),
  ([root, group]) => ({
    rootNode: root,
    nodes: group.length + 1
  })));
```

The comments I think are self explanatory. This is just grouping up the "nodes" by a common root node. Then I just take out the length of those groups. The `Map` structures certainly does hide some of the operation complexity though.

**Edit:** Just realized, you wanted the node count of the largest tree. At this point, I would call this a formatting issue since you already have your nodes grouped:

```
function largestTreeCount(nodes){
  let groups = groupByRootNode(nodes);
  let totalNodes = Array.from(groups, ([r, group]) => group.length+1);
  return Math.max(...totalNodes);
}
```

Comment: I just realised that ```['2 3'],['1 2']``` is returning 2 instead of 3 because the output is ```[ { rootNode: '2', nodes: 2 }, { rootNode: '1', nodes: 2 } ]```

Comment: @nanokozmos you are right, small logic flaw there. It should always check for children pairs in root nodes no matter if they are new roots or not.

Comment: Yeah but I have checked your update and it is still returning 2 instead of 3. Because the output is ```[ { rootNode: '1', nodes: 2 } ]``` right now

Comment: @nanokozmos I think it's fixed now. Took the liberty to rewrite it a bit. There's less repetition this way.

Answer (score 1):

You could build a tree with all nodes as reference in an object, get heads and count nested tries. Finally get the maximum value.

```js
const
    pairs = [[1, 3], [1, 4], [3, 5], [4, 6], [7, 8]],
    heads = new Set(pairs.map(([n]) => n)),
    references = {},
    count = nodes => nodes.reduce((s, n) => s + 1 + count(Object.keys(references[n])), 0);

pairs.forEach(([parent, child]) => {
    heads.delete(child);
    references[parent] = references[parent] || { };
    references[parent][child] = (references[child] = references[child] || { });
});

console.log(Math.max(...[...heads].map(n => count([n]))));
console.log(references);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you refactor your code without using nullish coalescing operator?:)

Answer (score 0):

Find all root nodes in linear time and space (e.g. by building a set of all nodes & child nodes). Then, use DFS to measure the size of each tree in linear time (O(V+E), but E is V-1).

Answer (score -2):

Slightly puzzled because it is most common for a Tree data structure to simply *record* how many nodes are currently in them, incrementing and decrementing the count as necessary.  (Trees often harbor other kinds of so-called "statistics.")